# Salesforce chatter photo upload trigger

Tags: image, salesforce, apex, profile, salesforce-chatter

When in salesforce I upload salesforce chatter profile picture i need to create the trigger which reacts to picture upload. Now trigger could print System.debug'I changed my profile pic'. Id doesn't work on User, ChaterFeedItem, ContentDocument. What would be correct approach. The final goal is to get chatter profile picture URL as the field for email template input.

The ultimate goal is to figure on which Object i have to write salesforce trigger?